# Switch View in AppDelegate (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, view, appdelegate

I need to set the starting View of my App depending on a user is registrated or not.
This will be done in AppDelegate:

```
       func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
            if(isUserRegistrated() == true){
                let vc : AnyObject! = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("isRegistrated")
                    self.showViewController(vc as UIViewController, sender: vc)
            }
            else{
                let vc : AnyObject! = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("isNOTRegistrated")
                    self.showViewController(vc as UIViewController, sender: vc)
            }
       }
```

At this point i got the error:
"Value of type AppDelegate has no member of storyboard"

Any conclusions ?

Comment: Have you registered your storyboard??

Comment: how do i register my storyboard ?

Answer (score 0):

**Sample:**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someViewController") as! UIViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: When I do so, I get the error: " Instants member storyboard cannot be used on type AppDelegate"